# How to add relationship beetween two different libraries in .NET Core

Tags: c#, database, .net-core, ef-code-first

I need build a link between two libraries in .NET Core using the code-first approach.

I need to build a link between the countries table from the standards library and the table with trade forms.

Both libraries operate on separate contexts.

Relationships between projects can be added unidirectionally because if you try to add a bidirectional constraint, you get a circular error.

Is there any way to build such a relationship?

```
public class CountryStandard
{
    [Key]
    public int IdCountryStandard { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Country")]
    [Display(Name = "Name Country")]
    [MaxLength(80, ErrorMessage = "Name max 80")]
    public string NameCountryStandard { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    //public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Standard> Standard { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TradeForms> TradeForms { get; set; }
}

public class TradeForms
{
    [Key]
    public int TradeFormsId { get; set; }
    /...
    .../
    public int IdCountryStandard { get; set; }
    public CountryStandard CountryStandard { get; set; }
}
```

After building the relationship, I would add to the Fluent API
And he did the database migration.

But I don't know if it is possible to build relationships between separate libraries from code-first in this way.

[image]

Comment: Can you specify the scenario? Maybe with more code?

Comment: I have added code with classes between which I want to build relationships

Comment: I download the state from the library of standards. After which the standards will be displayed in the form. Through the relations between classes, I would like to take the name of the state from the library of standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to do circular referencing in .NET.

**Solution 1 I recommend**

Merge Standard.DAL and Trade.DAL in one project DAL.

**Solution 2**

Remove in Standard.DAL all reference to Trade.DAL. For example with CountryStandard :

```cs
public class CountryStandard
{
    [Key]
    public int IdCountryStandard { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Standard> Standard { get; set; }
    // Remove - public virtual ICollection<TradeForms> TradeForms { get; set; }
}
```

**Solution 3**

If you really need this navigation property, you can apply the solution 2 and extend standard entities to add removed navigation properties. For example with Standard.DAL.CountryStandard, you can extend in the Trade.DAL project to :

```cs
namespace Trade.DAL
{
    public class TradeCountry : CountryStandard
    {
        public ICollection<TradeForms> TradeForms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then in the context :

```cs
namespace Trade.DAL
{
    public class TradeEntities : DbContext
    {
        ...

        public DbSet<TradeForms> TradeForms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TradeCountry> TradeCountries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining and writing the code